# How to move Hamburger Menu Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Does anyone know how to move hamburger menu before minicart in mobile view as shown below 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add/edit following css in you less file :

Find below code from below file path :

```
app\design\frontend\Orange\Orange-theme\Magento_Theme\web\css\source\_module.less
.logo {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0px;
    max-width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}

.nav-toggle {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    right: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    z-index: 14;
}
```

Find below code from below file path :

```
app\design\frontend\Orange\Orange-theme\Magento_Checkout\web\css\source\module\_minicart.less

  .minicart-wrapper {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 40px;
    }
```

**Your expected output** 
[image]

Comment: It's working thanks